# Boosting field in the mapping file not working with QueryString

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have an application where the users (clients) can activate different modules.
On the search, the user should be able to search a value in the entire index (for the modules he has activated).

The problem is that I also need to boost some field.

Currently I have this.

> mapping.yml

```
indexes:
    traveler:
        client: default
        finder: ~
        types:
            Country:
                mappings:
                    name: { boost: 10 }
                    code:
                    # additional info (irrelevant)
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model:  CoreBundle\Entity\Country
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
                serializer:
                    groups: [Default, elastica]
            Places:
                mappings:
                    name:
                    address:
                        type: "object"
                        properties:
                            city: ~
                            region: ~
                            country: ~
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model:  CoreBundle\Entity\Places
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
                serializer:
                    groups: [Default, elastica]
```

And in my service I have this :

```
$index = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.traveler');
$query = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($search);

# if the client has the module activated
foreach ($this->getClient()->getServices() as $service) {
    switch ($service->getService()->getTag()) {
        case "countries":
            $filters->addShould(
                new Type('Country')
            );
            break;
        case "places":
            $filters->addShould(
                new Type('Places')
            );
            break;
    }
}

$query = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($query, $filters);

// set result limit
$globalQuery = new Query();
$globalQuery->setQuery($query);
$globalQuery->setSize($limit);

// return result
return $index->find($query);
```

Now, for example, if I search "**Germany**", the "**Country**" result should be first in the result set, because I applied a boost to it in the yml mapping.
Instead, the first 5 or 6 results are for "**Places**" which have in their country address "**Germany**".

The boost is not applied (I tried with higher values, removing it ... results are not changed).

---

I found a way where it works, if I change my service like this, but I would prefer that it use the boost property defined in the mapping.

```
$query = new QueryString($search);
$query->setFields(array(
    '_all',
    'Country.name^10'
));
```

---

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is there another way to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: @keety Running on 1.7.5 (above is not supported by the Symfony2 FOSElasticaBundle)